# The distance to the farthest and closest points for each cluster - kmeans

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, k-means

In the image below, I have two data clusters. For a new data point (A), can I get the distance from A to the farthest points "with red circle" for each cluster and the distance to the closest points "with purple circles"?

simply, for each cluster, I need the distance from A "a new point" to the closest and the farthest points for each cluster.

Does Sklearn library provides a function for that, or I have to do that manually?!

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ones you've pointed out are not actually the closest and farthest ones. The one you've circled as the closes in the green class, only looks closes because of your different scaling on your two axis. An Euclidean distance would not give you that point as the closes point.

Other than that,yes you'd need to implement that yourself. Here's a sample code doing that:

Code:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

X = np.array([[1, 2], [1, 4], [1, 0],
              [4, 2], [4, 4], [4, 0]])

kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=2, random_state=0).fit(X)

kmeans.predict([[0, 0], [4, 4]])


from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import euclidean_distances

data = np.array([[5, 0], [-4, 10], [0, 3]])

dists = euclidean_distances(data, X)

for i in range(len(data)):
    print("data: %s" % str(data[i, :]))
    for x in range(kmeans.n_clusters):
        min_dist = min(dists[i, kmeans.labels_ == x])
        max_dist = max(dists[i, kmeans.labels_ == x])
        print("cluster: %d\n\tcloses: %s: %g\n\tfarthest: %s: %g" 
              % (x, 
                 str(X[dists[i, :] == min_dist, :]),
                 min_dist,
                 str(X[dists[i, :] == max_dist, :]),
                 max_dist))
```

Output:

```
data: [5 0]
cluster: 0
    closes: [[1 0]]: 4
    farthest: [[1 4]]: 5.65685
cluster: 1
    closes: [[4 0]]: 1
    farthest: [[4 4]]: 4.12311
data: [-4 10]
cluster: 0
    closes: [[1 4]]: 7.81025
    farthest: [[1 0]]: 11.1803
cluster: 1
    closes: [[4 4]]: 10
    farthest: [[4 0]]: 12.8062
data: [0 3]
cluster: 0
    closes: [[1 2]
 [1 4]]: 1.41421
    farthest: [[1 0]]: 3.16228
cluster: 1
    closes: [[4 2]
 [4 4]]: 4.12311
    farthest: [[4 0]]: 5
```